# Google BigQuery: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not available at some locations

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** views (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) to access metadata of my datasets' tables and columns. However, for some datasets (especially those that are located in Asian or European regions), my INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries at BigQuery's Query Editor received this kind of error:

> "Not found: Dataset abc:xyz.INFORMATION_SCHEMA was not found in
>   location...".

Is this because of the unavailability of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA at the location? Also, my newly created dataset in Asian regions do have the INFORMATION_SCHEMA available, only the old ones (created before December 2018) are having this problem.

Comment: What is the query you use?

Comment: Frank, could you collect the query and job id which triggers "information_schema was not found" error and `Create new BigQuery issue` on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Hi @khan, this is the query that I used: SELECT * FROM abc.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (abc is the name of the dataset).

Comment: Hi @YunZhang, thank you for the instruction. I'm creating the new issue now.

Comment: This is still a problem, years later.